# How to best get value from previous row with timestamp constraints?

Tags: google-bigquery

In our dw based on BigQuery we handle pretty large volumes of sensor data coming in. Out of these we create different data marts for specific use.

We do incremental updates of some of the marts. One of these marts need to have the previous row's value added to current row. That is easy to do for full update, but how can this best be done for incremental updates?

Consider the following sample where the incremental is based on date:

```
WITH sampledata AS
 (SELECT 1 as id, 1 as value, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-17 2:51:45' as dt
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:54:11'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:59:01'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:01:17'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,4, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:05:42'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:06:24'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,4, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:06:36'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:07:41'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,4, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:08:58'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,1, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:10:14')

select 
  id,
  value,
  LAG(value ) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC) as prev_value,
  dt
from sampledata
where DATE(dt) > "2016-10-17"
```

Results:
| id | value | prev_value | dt |
| -- | ----- | ---------- | -- |
| 1  | 2     | null       | 2016-10-18 02:54:11 UTC |
| 1  | 3     | 2          | 2016-10-18 02:59:01 UTC |
| 1  | 2     | 3          | 2016-10-18 03:01:17 UTC |
...and so on..

You see that the first row gets null as its prev_value because if the limiting date factor in the where clause (needed for the incremental updates). We've tried self-joining / cross-joining the table, which works, but it is just too slow for the amount of data we have.

Anyone have advice on what can be tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
select * from (
  select 
    id,
    value,
    LAG(value ) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC) as prev_value,
    dt
  from sampledata
)
where DATE(dt) > "2016-10-17"
```

with output

[image]